# reactjs - how to tell a "distant" component to re-render?

Tags: reactjs

At the top right of my web application I display the username if the user is currently signed in, and "not logged in" if not. This component get's its information about the users signed in state by checking a key in redux.

Users sign in by visiting a signin form.  The sign in form and the top-right-bar-login-state are very separate components, both deep down separate branches of the reactjs component hierarchy.

I just can't wrap my head around how I can get the top-right-bar-login-state to re-render once the user has successfully logged in via the signin form.

Can anyone suggest what I should be doing?

Comment: show us some code, but it seems like you should be using the same reducer to log in and to store the name of the user signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about it in terms of one component causing another component to re-render. Your component should re-render **after a change in your store**. It shouldn't know what made the change either.

There are a few ways to listen for changes in your stores, with the most popular being [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). It will allow you to wrap the component you want to re-render in a *connected container* that knows about your store and depends on some of its data.

When there's a change to the fragment of data that your container cares about, it will re-render the React component inside of it.

1. `<SignInForm />` dispatches an action.
2. One of your reducers calculates a new state.
3. Your `<TopRightLoginBar />` container re-renders.

Comment: Any idea how to do this without using Redux?

Comment: Lots of messy components passing event handlers up and down, or with a global event emitter. Although, it's worth remembering that the Flux architecture exists because neither of these options worked particularly well.